# Header script causing alert

Tags: jscript

When loading the page I get a alert box with unidentified in, when remove this bit code it goes. I need this as it makes the menu work.

Going in a bit blind on this so wasn't sure what it doesn't like, I suppose I should be asking what does this actually mean?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var loadEvents = new Array();
        function addInitFunction(func) { loadEvents.push( { 'func':func, 'seq':-1 } ); }
        function addLoadEvent(func, seq) { loadEvents.push( { 'func':func, 'seq':seq } ); }
        var linkver="-65";
        var IP="";
        var proto="https:";
        var def_proto="http:";
      </script>
```

Narrowed it down to this line

```
function addInitFunction(func) { loadEvents.push( { 'func':func, 'seq':-1 }); }
```

I've also found what I think is the function with the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Move responsive divs
  function homeRespChange(from, too, source) {
    respMoveContent('respHeaderLogin', { 'default':'respMove_HeaderLogin_default', 'phone':'respMove_HeaderLogin_phone' });
  }

  function homeInit() {
      responsiveKick();
  }

  addInitFunction('homeInit');
  addInitFunction('menuFixup');
  addInitFunction('setWallp');
  addInitFunction('tidyFunc');
  addInitFunction('moveBasket');
  addInitFunction('loginMenu');

  function mess() {
    alertX('EUCookieMessage_Holder');
  }
  //addLoadEvent(mess);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us what func is?

Comment: Sorry, bit of a newbie at this. So which part is the name of the function i'm looking for

Comment: Got it, was an old function being called but a general name so I missed it.

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, you just mentioned the function made me find the answer